# InnerHtml not working with ASP

Tags: asp.net, webforms, innerhtml

I have the following test code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyDiv.InnerHtml = "1=" + Request.Form.Count.ToString();      // WORKING

        if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            MyDiv.InnerHtml = "2=" + Request.Form.Count.ToString();  // NOT WORKING
        }  
    }
```

Why is this happening? Do I have to use the Page.IsPostback feature? I try to avoid that because it works poorly with my javascript code. I use jquery ajax when posting data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because the whole ASP page is not reloaded when you do your AJAX call, and therefore MyDiv is not being updated in your browser.

You need to do something more like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDiv.InnerHtml = "1=" + Request.Form.Count.ToString();      // WORKING

    if (Request.Form.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form.Count.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }  
}
```

From a code-maintenance point of view, it would probably be better to write a special page or handler for receiving the ajax postbacks, but I'm just sticking with the one page for simplicity.

And then add something like this to the settings parameter of your ajax call:

```
success: function(data){
     $("<%=MyDiv.ClientId%>").innerHTML = "2=" + data.responseText;
}
```